# How to use global Node packages with VS Code

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

If Node.js packages are globally installed, they can be used by Node.js applications. But Visual Studio Code will not accept these packages and indicate an error, as long as these packages are not installed locally in the project directory (inside the subdirectory *node_modules*).

For example:

```
import * as net from 'net';
```

... `'net'` is marked with a red underline as long as you do not install `npm install --save @types/node`. If you install that package globally via `npm -g install @types/node`, the package would be available, but *code (V 1.17.1)* will not recognize it.

So my question, is there a way to configure code to recognize global installed Node.js packages?

Comment: Interesting question, I can't tell you why it wouldn't work but I would recommend you to run `npm install --save-dev @types/node` so that any other developer who's also working on the project don't need to have types/node installed globally.

Comment: I do it like you, I install all packages locally inside the project. But it's interesting why code cannot recognize globally installed packages. Because if packages are installed globally, the project can be executed and it will work. Code will indicate an error, which is definitely a wrong indication.

Comment: You can create an issue in the VSCode's git repo, they are very responsive and I bet you will get an answer there ;-).

Comment: Now posted on  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36615

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliSense for global modules is not supported as of VS Code 1.18. Please file an new issue [against TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new) if you really need this feature

However you really should not need to install @types packages when working with JavaScript in VS Code. [Automatic types acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition) should kick in and download these for you. There are also explicitly force these types to be downloaded by adding the following to your `jsconfig.json`

```
"typeAcquisition": {
    "include": [
        "node"
    ]
}
```

For TypeScript projects, you should install @types locally as dev dependencies.

Comment: You are right, it seems to be a typescript issue. The `typeAcquisition` in jsconfig.json does not work on typescript level. Environment variables like `NODE_PATH` or global module path setting inside tsconfig.js (compilerOptions/typeRoots) are also ignored by typescript. As long as type definitions are not installed locally, transpilation fails.

Comment: Creating a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46946205/how-to-use-global-node-packages-with-typescript) for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a workaround/partial answer (and I cannot comment yet):

As long as all your scripts that you don't want to create a full package.json for (e.g., simple standalone scripts) have a common root directory in the filesystem, vscode seems to recognize a "global" package.json and node_modules directory at that root.

More concretely, you could run `npm i -D @types/node` in your home directory, and vscode finds the types for all scripts somewhere below the home directory (i.e., `$HOME/**/*.ts`).

(Only tested on Linux with a single file, and vscode 1.64.1.)