# How to use global Node packages with Typescript

Tags: typescript

Using global packages is possible by install them via `npm install -g ...`.
If Typescript types are installed in this way, they are also available in the global folder, for example `/usr/lib/node_modules` on a linux system.

When transpiling a typescript source file with *tsc*, a compiler error is printed out and the transpilation fails.

`src/main.ts(3,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'.`

However, I would expect that either environmental variables like `NODE_PATH` or configuration settings in file `tsconfig.json` like

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "typeRoots": [
             "/usr/lib/node_modules/@types"
        ]
     }
}
```

could solve that problem (see also [Typescript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)).

But all these settings are ignored. Only installing types locally in the project helps.

So my question, why are the settings in `tsconfig.json` ignored and are there any possibilities to use globally installed types packages

[Example project](https://github.com/ManfredSteiner/stackovf_46946205):

After `npm install` you can run this project with `npm start` if all other dependencies are installed globally. Only 7 packages are installed with:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.38",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.31",
    "@types/sprintf-js": "^1.1.0"
 }
```

If I remove the local directory `node_modules` you get the errors

```
src/main.ts(2,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'sprintf-js'.
src/main.ts(3,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'.
```

... although these packages are available in the global package folder `/usr/lib/node_modules`.

Comment: Think you need to refine your question a bit. Are you trying to install express globally and then point your local TS compiler to also use that global folder i guess? In that case your 'importing' and even though the types might get resolved your module imports won't. For that you need to use paths. 

You can read some explenations here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11137

Comment: I would expect, that if I install express globally (and the builded project would work without any locally installed packages), also the Typescript compiler is able to import modules from global directory. But it seems, that this is not working, also in case if I define that path in *tsconfig.json*.

Comment: Have you a found a solution for this?

Comment: For me setting "typeRoots" works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue as described above and for me the `path` property worked. Note that this is relative to basePath as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping). See the example below:

```
      "baseUrl": "/Users/myUser/Projects/myProject",
        "paths": {
            "bignumber.js": [
                "../../.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/bignumber.js"
            ],
            "moment": [
                "../../.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/moment"
            ],
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `tsc` does not use nodes module resolution by default unless you set `module: "commonjs"` in the tsconfig. Have you tried setting `moduleResolution: "node"`

Answer (score 0):

**Linux** solution.

I've noticed that copying `node_modules` to the user's root folder solves the import errors.

So, you can simply copy `node_modules` folder or (**much better**) make a symbolic link to your node_modules folder.

For example, on my Linux system, after having made a symbolic link:

```
ln --symbolic ~/node-v18.12.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/ ~/
```

imports no more produced errors (I needed to restart my IDE).

Of course, replace `node-v18.12.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/` with your location.